# Fibonacci sequence function producing incorrect values

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, fibonacci, dynamic-arrays

I am creating a Fibonacci function that is producing unexpected and inaccurate results. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a simple way to correct this?

```js
const fib=(c,f=[0,1],r=0)=>c>1?(f.push(f.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)),f.shift(),fib(c-1,f,1)):(r?f[1]:(c<0?NaN:f[c]));
fib(100); // -> 354224848179262000000,

// Correct 100th digit where `fib(0) === 0` would be 354224848179261915075
```

Comment: about impossible to read that code with that all reducing, shifting, NaN and pushing in the same line

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, this is a fairly common issue with big integers and very small/long decimal numbers. There are a few libraries out there to resolve this issue when it comes to decimal numbers, but the good news is that JavaScript has native support for big integers that will solve this issue immediately. Just use and return the BigInt type and the number will be accurate.

Unfortunately, you cannot convert this number format back into a normal number without it rounding back to the incorrect value you mentioned, but it will stringify just fine, so it should work for almost all uses.

Use this:

```js
const fib=(c,f=[0n,1n],r=0)=>c>1?(f.push(f.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0n)),f.shift(),fib(c-1,f,1)):(r?f[1]:(c<0?NaN:f[c]));

console.log(fib(100).toString()); // -> "354224848179261915075"
```

You can read up more on the BigInt type here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: Wow so simple! I actually tried playing with BigInt as well and considered that but couldn't get it to work on my end. Probably a dumb typo. Thanks for the quick turnaround. This will work just fine for me.